# PHP Variable from String with Javascript popup

Tags: javascript, php, variables, popup

In /var/www/html/msg.txt is just one word "Test".

Can someone please tell me why this doesn't work?

```
 echo "<script>alert('$tes');</script>";
```

Complet php code:

```
<?php
    $ma="Test";
    $tes = file_get_contents("/var/www/html/msg.txt");

    echo "$tes"; //works

    echo "<script>alert('$ma');  //works
    </script>";

//but if this

         echo "<script>alert('$tes'); // doesn't work!!!! Why?
         </script>";
    ?>
```

how can I do it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Most likely you have a line break in that file, so the resulting code is:

```
<script>alert('Test
'); 
</script>;
```

Which is wont work, you can confirm this by looking at the source, and/or it will be erroring out in the browser console.

Comment: Yes, you are right! If I change file to "Test" and   echo "<script>alert($tes); </script>";
works! Thank You!!!

Comment: np, glad you sorted it

Answer (score -1):

The problem is with your file_get_contents. Probably you are setting an incorerect path, or the file that you are trying to access doesn't have the right permissions

Comment: No, it is not permissions issue, otherwise   "echo "$tes";"   would not have worked